# MS Access VBA Export records in Access database to Excel that meet multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am amateur in MS Access VBA and I would like to ask you for help.

I have MyTable in Access, with many fields, 5 of them are:

```
[Date]                format DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS
[Priority]            ("Urgent", "Normal")
[MOC]                 ("Yes","No")
[AffectProduction]    ("Yes","No")
[Status]              (" ","Following","Closed","Cancelled")
```

I have a userform for choosing conditon what to export, with  have 6 fields

```
[FromDate]            textbox with Date Picker
[ToDate]              textbox with Date Picker
[Priority]            Option group             ("Urgent", "Normal", "All")
[MOC]                 Option group             ("Yes","No", "All")
[AffectProduction]    Option group             ("Yes","No", "All")
[Status]              Option group             (" ","Following","Closed","Cancelled","All")
```

I want to export all record that meet condition have been chosen on above form. (Choose "All" that mean no filter with that field)

I can make if or select case statement but it too many case, is there any way to help me. Below is some of my nope code only Priority and Status.
Please help me to do the better way! Many thanks

```
Do While Not rs.EOF
            If ((rs!Date >= dFromDate) And (rs!Date <= dToDate)) Then
                Select Case True
                    Case ((intPriority = 1) And (intStatus = 1))
                        If ((rs!Priority = "Urgent") And (rs!Status = "Following")) Then                                                          
                            Call ExportData(rs, xlSheet, i)
                        End If                            
                    Case ((intPriority = 1) And (intStatus = 2))
                        If ((rs!Priority = "Urgent") And (rs!Status = "Closed")) Then                                
                            Call ExportData(rs, xlSheet, i)
                        End If                            
                    Case ((intPriority = 1) And (intStatus = 3))
                        If (rs!Priority = "Urgent") Then                                
                            Call ExportData(rs, xlSheet, i)
                        End If                        
                    Case ((intPriority = 2) And (intStatus = 1))
                        If ((rs!Priority = "Normal") And (rs!Status = "Following")) Then                                
                            Call ExportData(rs, xlSheet, i)
                        End If                        
                    Case ((intPriority = 2) And (intStatus = 2))
                        If ((rs!Priority = "Normal") And (rs!Status = "Closed")) Then                                
                            Call ExportData(rs, xlSheet, i)
                        End If                        
                    Case ((intPriority = 2) And (intStatus = 3))
                        If (rs!Priority = "Normal") Then                                
                            Call ExportData(rs, xlSheet, i)                                
                        End If                        
                    Case ((intPriority = 3) And (intStatus = 1))
                        If (rs!Status = "Following") Then                                
                            Call ExportData(rs, xlSheet, i)
                        End If                        
                    Case ((intPriority = 3) And (intStatus = 2))
                        If (rs!Status = "Closed") Then                                
                            Call ExportData(rs, xlSheet, i)
                        End If                        
                    Case ((intPriority = 3) And (intStatus = 3))                            
                        Call ExportData(rs, xlSheet, i)
                End Select
                i = i + 1
           End If               
           rs.MoveNext    
        Loop
```

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: Could you not build a query based on **Priority** and **Status**? You can then use the returned record set to populate your sheet rather than checking each record

Comment: As @June7 has said, build the SQL for a recordset using code similar to the link posted, and then use `CopyFromRecordset` to dump the whole set of data into Excel.

Comment: Thanks @June7 and Applecore. I will try that way

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to include WHERE in sql condition
SELECT * FROM table WHERE [] = ...

Comment: Thanks @Boni, I have that code already, but I just post the code for select case

Answer (score 0):

@Trung Nguyen
Code:

```
Dim record as DAO.Recordset
Dim db as DAO.Database
Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase ("C:\....")
Set record = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT ...",dbopenDynaset)
' see previous posting
Sheets("name of sheet").Range("A1") record
' Excel-sheet where you want to have data copied 
' for the WHERE-condition more actions may be taken with WHERE cond1 AND/OR cond2
```

Hope this helps ;0)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use DAO combined with SQL in VBA for this
Example set db =database.openrecordset(SELECT * FROM table,dbdynaset)
and then in Excel Sheets(namesheet).Range.copyfromrecordset db

Comment: This is not really an answer, adding nothing more than has been made in the comments.

Comment: Could you please explain more detail @Boni? Thanks